# Customizing individual biblabels?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the standard `article` class and bib style `unsrt` with LaTeX and BibTeX.  I would like to customize individual biblabels in my list of references, for instance starring certain items as follows:

> [1] A. Uthor ...
>
> *[2] B. Uthor ...
>
> [3] C. Uthor ...

where the labels should be right-aligned so that the starred ones stand out.  Thanks to this forum, I know how to customize all the labels with:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\mbox{$\star \left[ \right.$}#1\mbox{$\left. \right]$}}

\makeatother
```

but how can I customize only specific ones?  A solution based on BibTeX tags would be prefered, but others will be considered.

Answer (score 4):

It mostly depends on how you decide what entries must be starred. I assume that you can decide via a substring of the key.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gander2001,
 author={Gladstone Gander},
 title={How to be lucky},
 journal={Nature},
 pages={1-33},
 volume={42},
 year={2001},
}
@article{ducks2002,
 author={Donald Duck and Fethry Duck},
 title={How to be unlucky},
 journal={Nature},
 pages={34-44},
 volume={43},
 year={2002},
}
@book{scrooge1901,
 author={Scrooge McDuck},
 title={My first golden nugget in {Klondike}},
 publisher={Yukon Press},
 address={Whitehorse},
 year={1901},
}
@book{scrooge1990,
 author={Scrooge McDuck},
 title={How to manage zillion of dollars},
 publisher={McDuck Press},
 address={Duckburg},
 year={1990},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setspeciallist}{ m }
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_mmakster_special_list_seq { , } { #1 }
 }

\cs_set_eq:Nc \mmakster_original_bibitem:n { @bibitem }

\seq_new:N \g_mmakster_special_list_seq
\bool_new:N \l_mmakster_star_bool
\cs_set_protected:cpn { @bibitem } #1
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l_mmakster_star_bool
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_mmakster_special_list_seq
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #1 } { ##1 } 
     { \bool_set_true:N \l_mmakster_star_bool \seq_map_break: }
   }
  \mmakster_original_bibitem:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_set_protected:cpn { @biblabel } #1
 {
  \bool_if:NT \l_mmakster_star_bool { \leavevmode\llap{*} }[#1]
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setspeciallist{gander,duck}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

With this the two entries "Gander" and "Duck and Duck" have a key that has one of the strings in `\setspeciallist` as substring, so they will be starred.

[image]