# biblatex: Customise individual labels in bibliography section

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex, I would like to manually adjust some few labels (I mean: [1], [2]) in the bibliography section and the text body of the document.

The same question was posed for bibtex, see [Customizing individual biblabels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78792/59177) while I am interested in a solution for bib**la**tex.

The idea is that all own publications are indicated as [P1], [P2] etc.

```
[P1] Gladstone Gander. How to be lucky. Nature, 42:1-33, 2001.
```

while all other publications are indicated as [3], [4] etc.

```
[2] Donald Duck and Fethry Duck. How to be unlucky. Nature, 43:34-44, 2002.
```

Then, one could use `\nocite{}` at the beginning of the mainmatter to make sure that all own publications appear on the top of the bibliography section and that numbering of all other references continues with the next integer number.

In case that might be helpful, I load biblatex as:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-verb,backend=bibtex,sorting=none,sortcites=true,firstinits=true,isbn=false,maxcitenames=99,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
```

Thanks in advance for some hints!

Comment: You also can use `bibliography categories` or add a `keyword` field to your data.  See § 3.6.7, p.79, *Bibliography categories*,  and § 3.11.4, pp. 109–111, *Subdivided bibliographies* in the documentation.

Comment: Please add a [Minimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4408/) so that we can more easily help you. This is not difficult to do in biblatex, I don't think, but creating an example from scratch is no fun ;).

Comment: Closely related with modern solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573315/124229

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly easy. You will just have to have a way to distinguish those entries with a modified label. There are at least two ways to do that, the two ways are fundamentally different though.

Use `keywords`, you can just add `keywords = {modlabel}` to the `.bib` entry and filter the bibliography with `keyword=modlabel` and `notkeyword=modlabel`.
In this case, you will decide in the `.bib` file whether an entry is to have the modified numbering or not.

When you use a *bibliography category* approach, this decision is delayed and only made in the actual `.tex` document. We define a bibliography category

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{modlabel}
```

Add the respective entries to this category via `\addtocategory{modlabel}{<key>}` and filter the bibliography with `category=modlabel` and `notcategory=modlabel`.

You will have to load `biblatex` with the `defernumbers=true` option for both approaches to work properly.

The bibliography for the prefixed entries is then printed in a new `refcontext` with option `labelprefix=P`.

MWE (which uses bibliography categories)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-verb, backend=bibtex, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{modlabel}
\addtocategory{modlabel}{cicero,geer}

\begin{document}
\nocite{geer,wilde,cicero,markey,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric}
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[category=modlabel]
\end{refcontext}
\printbibliography[notcategory=modlabel,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the output: a bibliography with labels P1, P2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

---

In order to avoid the slightly increased spacing between the two `\printbibliography`s add the following to your preamble

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {}
  {\item}

\newenvironment{spacedbib}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
```

And enclose the `\pritntbibliograpy` commands in this new `spacedbib` environment like so

```
\begin{spacedbib}
\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[category=modlabel]
\end{refcontext}
\printbibliography[notcategory=modlabel,heading=none]
\end{spacedbib}
```

Comment: Works fine! Now, the only question, I have left would be: how to control the distance between the two sets of references? But that is only for curiosity...

Comment: @Rantanplan I had hoped it was too subtle to be noted, but should have known better. See the edit for a very crude work-around. A separate question about the spacing between two (or more) consecutive `\printbibliography`s might be worth asking, I suppose, maybe someone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Wow! There might be a small mistake; when compiling, I receive an error saying `Something is wrong, perhaps a missing \item?`.

Comment: @Rantanplan I see, that is not very nice. The problem occurs only if the bibliography is empty (i.e. if there is no entry with the corresponding keywords). Naturaly then, this also happens on the first run, if no `.bbl` file is present. If you push through with the compilation despite the error and run BibTeX/Biber the `.bbl` is created and the following LaTeX compilation works.

Comment: @Rantanplan I cannot think of a nice work around for that. So I suggest you ask a new question about making two consecutive `\printbibliography`s follow each other seamlessly.

Comment: Now, I opened a separate question about this space where I used @moewe 's example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241231/59177

Comment: Does not work anymore since biblatex 3.6 (Oct 2016), ``prefixnumbers`` was moved to ``refcontext`` and renamed to ``labelprefix``

Comment: @derptank Thanks for the heads up! Updated to hopefully work with a current `biblatex`.