# Biblatex: control space between two \printbibliography sections

Tags: biblatex

I am running **biblatex** to print two bibliography sections using

```
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=P,category=modlabel]
\printbibliography[notcategory=modlabel,heading=none]
```

Between both sections there is a slightly larger space than between bibliography entries. Is it possible to reduce that space?

Here, an example where the space is between [P2] and [3]:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-verb, backend=bibtex, sorting=none,    defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{modlabel}
\addtocategory{modlabel}{cicero,geer}

\begin{document}
\nocite{geer,wilde,cicero,markey,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=P,category=modlabel]
\printbibliography[notcategory=modlabel,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Thanks for some hints!

*This is a question that follows https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236650/59177. Both the picture and the MWE are copied from moewe's answer.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-verb, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}%backend=bibtex,
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{modlabel}
\addtocategory{modlabel}{cicero,geer}

\begin{document}

\nocite{geer,wilde,cicero,markey,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=P,category=modlabel]
\vspace{-2\topsep}
\printbibliography[notcategory=modlabel,heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]