# Cite all @article-s in the bibliography (BiBLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is there any way to cite all articles in the bibliography (i.e. BiBTeX entries with `@article` type)?

I know there is a `type` option in the `\printbibliography` command. I want something like `\cite[type=article]{*}`...

**UPD:**
For example, I have 100 articles in the bib file and 100 proceedings.
I want to print the bibliography that shows the articles first, then the proceedings.

If I use the following code

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Proceedings}]
```

I will have bad numeration (since the articles and the proceeding are "mixed" in the bib-file:

```
Articles:
1. Article#1
3. Article#2
4. Article#3
...
183. Arctice#100

Proceedings:
2. Proceeding#1
5. Proceeding#5
...
200. Proceeding#100
```

P.S. Manually citing all the papers in the correct order (`\cite{article1, article2, ..., article100, proceeding1, proceeding2, ..., proceeding100}`) is not a good option.

Comment: `\nocite{*}\printbibliography[type=article,title={Bibliography}]`?

Comment: Do you mean `citing`all articles, or `printing`all articles at the end?

Comment: I want to cite all papers in the same order as in the bib-file. After that, I want to cite all proceeding in the same order as in the bib-file. I.e I want to have something like: `Articles [1–20], Proceedings [21–25]`. Note that the articles are cited first (they have ascending numbers from 1 to 20)

Comment: I think you mean they must appear in the bibliography  in the same order as you cite them? The citation order is just fixed by  where *you* write the `\cite` command…

Comment: They will appear in the biblography in this order if I cite all the articles before citing the proceedings. This is exactly what I am asking: "How to cite all articles. After that, how to cite all proceedings".

Comment: If your main aim is to get a specific sorting in the bibliography you should better define this sorting.

Comment: OK, so I want the following sorting: first, all articles; second, all proceedings. How can I define sorting like this (assume I have `\cite{*}` command in the text). (Once again, I don't want to write a long `\cite{article1, article2, article3, article4, ...}` command, since I have hundreds of references in my bib file).

Comment: Since you only want your bibliography to sort by type, what about http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6959/35864? Maybe together with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241231/35864 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236650/35864 for spacing between the different bibliographies.

Comment: The numbering is the main problem (see update in the question)

Comment: Aha! But did you use `defernumbers=true` as explained in the example? If the problem persists, please consider posting a full MWE for us to play around with (using `bIblatex-examples.bib` so you don't even have to use your private `.bib` file).

Comment: You are right! `defernumbers=true` solves the problem.

Comment: @moewe I guess that makes this one a duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think so, yes. Since this question has an open bounty though, it cannot be closed. Incidentally, the bounty was offered just a few minutes after my comment with the duplicate answer. So we will have to wait, I guess.

Comment: @moewe You could consider to post a short answer so that bcp can give you that bounty. We can still close afterwards.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It wouldn't feel right parachuting in with just that duplicate behind me and taking all the credit ...

Comment: @moewe haha, very noble. OK, I see it is just one day left, so we can wait. But still I guess, bcp would prefer to give you some 50 points for pointing to the solution than to waste them. Doesn't matter...