# How to change bibliography numbering to squared brackets?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the scientific report template on overleaf and I am now facing a problem with the bibliography style. the current code is as below:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem {1} Jardine, Andrew K.S.,Lin, Daming, Banjevic,Dragan
\end{thebibliography}
```

and shows as above
[image]

but what i want it to look like is as below:

[image]

Appreciate anyone's help on this. thank you.

Comment: look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78792/customizing-individual-biblabels I have no much information from you question, but I think, for your purposes `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]}
\makeatother`

Comment: Since you are using a manual `thebibliography` you are neither using `biblatex` nor BibTeX, so I have removed these two tags.

Comment: The exact solution will depend on the document class and other bibliography/citation-related packages you use. So to be sure you get an answer that really helps you, please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).